# how to get previous record where another column is equal to

Tags: laravel, eloquent

This is how to get previous record but i want to add another 'where'

```
$previous = User::where('id', '<', $user->id)->max('id');
```

I tried

```
$previous = User::where(['anotherColumn'=>$anotherColumn], ['id', '<', $user->id])->max('id');
```

but gives the wrong record

look at the picture below i want to get 578 where id < 580 and document_id = 244

[image]

Comment: Can you give an example of your input, the expected output and actual output? Your example contains a lot of variables but we can't see what's in them.

Comment: i added a picture

Comment: on the second example you have a spelling mistake `['anotherColumn'=>$anotherColumn]` should be `['anotherColumn', =>, $anotherColumn']`

Answer (score 0):

i did it using this

```
History::where('document_id', '=', $document_id)->where('id', '<', $id)->max('id');
```

thank you for your effort :)